# "Why does this title have unnecessary quotation marks?"

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

No other Help Center titles are enclosed in quotation marks, apart from this one:

[image: quotation marks]

On top of inconsistency, this results in a nested quotation. Removing the outer quotation marks will improve readability.

Also, there are only a few Help Center titles that use single quote marks at all: most of them use double quote marks, which are far superior.

Comment: We're just hoping to get the attention of [this blogger](http://www.unnecessaryquotes.com/).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Ok, "fine". I've "removed" those "superfluous" quotation marks, and "replaced" the inner single-quotes with "normal" ones.

I hope you're "happy" now.